# Preset custom fields

Tags: plugins, custom-field, metabox

I'm creating a wordpress plugin which will create a custom post with custom fields like "time", "rating" etc whose will be fillable in admin. So far all tutorials I've seen only showing how enable "custom-fields" in the plugin, but I want those fields to be predefined and available in the post creation form.
so far my plugin is :

```
    function create_test_recipe_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Test Recipe', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Test Recipe', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
        ...
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Test Recipe', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => '',
        'supports' => array('title','excerpt', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'cooking_time_meta_box' //<--added cb
    );
    register_post_type( 'custompost', $args );

    }       
    
    add_action( 'init', 'create_test_recipe_cpt', 0 );

    function cooking_time_meta_box() {

    $screens = get_post_types();

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'cooking-time',
            __( 'Cooking Time', 'sitepoint' ),
            'cooking_time_meta_box_callback',
            $screen
        );

    }
}

function cooking_time_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( 'cooking_time_nonce', 'cooking_time_nonce' );

    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cooking_time', true );

    echo '<input type="number" style="width:100%" id="cooking_time" name="cooking_time" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" />';
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_test_recipe_cpt', 0 );


function save_cooking_time_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['cooking_time'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['cooking_time'], 'cooking_time' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    }
    else {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['cooking_time'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cooking_time'] );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_cooking_time', $my_data );
}
    
    add_action( 'save_post', 'save_cooking_time_meta_box_data' );

    function cooking_time_before_post( $content ) {

    global $post;

    $cooking_time = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cooking_time', true ) );

    $notice = "<div class='sp_cooking_time'>$cooking_time</div>";

    return $notice . $content;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'cooking_time_before_post' );
```

please suggest how to preset those field programmatically

UPDATED: so far I managed to add one field called `cooking_time` by using `register_meta_box_cb`. But new field is not being filled up after saving changes of post editing

[image]

Comment: I've removed the request for recommendations of tutorials as recommendations are off topic here. Are you using a fields library/plugin? Or have code for metaboxes or sidepanels? Or is this the native custom fields table where you have to write the meta key and the meta value in the table? Remember this isn't a discussion board so you'll need your question to be clear and specific, any detail you can add will help others write a good answer

Comment: I don't use any plugins and I won't be using any plugins except of one I'm creating. I just need to create custom post type with additional fields. Simple as that.Thats my test assignment

Comment: I see, can you answer the other questions in my comment? I asked multiple questions, in particular, do you have code for metaboxes/side panels, or iis this the native custom fields table where you have to write the meta key and the meta value in the table by hand?

Comment: I've updated my question with what I have achieved so far